# 100% Height Div inside another 100% div

Tags: css, html, height

I've used CSS before (copy/paste, templates, etc.) but this is the first time I'm trying to do it all my own from scratch. So, sorry if this is stupid, but I looked around and couldn't find an answer.

I want a header, then in the main body, a static width navigation on the left, next to that on the right, a big content div, and below everything, the footer.

I have this:

```
<div id = "header">
  Header
</div>

<div id = "body_wrapper">
  <div id = "nav_container">
    nav
  </div>
  <div id = "content_container">
    content     
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
        body, html
    {
      margin:0;
      height:100%;
    }

    #master_wrapper
    {
      width:100%;
      min-height:100%;
      background:#57a957;
    }

    #header
    {
      width:100%;
      height:60px;
      background:#1A2127;
    }

    #body_wrapper
    {
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
    }

    #nav_container
    {
      height:100%;
      min-height:100%;
      background:#b94a48;
      width:200px;
      float:left;
    }

    #content_container
    {
      height:100%;
      min-height:100%;
      background:#7a43b6;
          margin-right:0;
      float:left;
      margin-right:0;
          margin-left:0;
    }
```

I want nav_container to span 100% of the height between the header and footer.
I set the body and html height to 100%, and the height of nav_container to 100%, and when I put EVERYTHING in a wrapper, this happens: http://jsfiddle.net/J4u8k/
I want the red to go 100%.

When I take the div that wraps everything out, then I get this:
http://jsfiddle.net/64JFG/
Which is a little more correct, except that now there's "extra" space at the bottom that you have to scroll.

The scrolling at the bottom is the issue. It looks like it's taking 100% of the body + the height of the header.

Any ideas? Again, sorry if this is stupid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"> Header </div>
    <div id="content"> 
        <div id="nav">Nav </div>
        <div id="article"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"> Footer </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper
{
    margin 0px auto;
    padding:0px;
    width:1000px;
}

#header
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:Black;
    width:1000px;
    height:100px;
}
#footer
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:Black;
    width:1000px;
    height:50px;
}

#content
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
        width:1000px;
    height:500px;
}

#nav
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
        width:250px;
    height:500px;
}

#article
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    float:right;
    background-color:green;
        width:750px;
    height:500px;
}
```

**Fiddle : ** http://jsfiddle.net/64JFG/3/

Answer (score 0):

I think you've put too many *height:100%* in here. If the body_wrapper is a real height instead of a percentage your code will work

```
#body_height {
    height: 400px;
}
```

Also I don't think your content container needs to float left, but YMMV

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/J4u8k/2/

Add content and nav styles position:fixed;

```
#nav_container
{
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
background:#b94a48;
width:200px;
float:left;
    position:fixed;
}

#content_container
{
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
background:#7a43b6;
margin-right:0;
float:left;
margin-right:0;
margin-left:200px;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: If content div has a lot of text, you can't scroll to the bottom because you've set fixed position for that div.

Answer (score 0):

```
body, html{
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#master_wrapper{
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background:#57a957;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#header{    
    height:60px;
    background:#1A2127;
}

#nav_container{ 
    background:#b94a48;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
//kinds of hack for column 100%
    margin-bottom: -30000px;
    padding-bottom: 29999px;
}

#content_container{
    margin-bottom: -30000px;
    padding-bottom: 29999px;
    background:#7a43b6; 
    float:left; 
}
```